# Sysbase IQ Export and Import

Tags: sybase

I am Sybase BO Developer.

Looking for possible option top copy data from Sybase IQ production and load to QA/UAT.

Need only subset of data(based on dates), not full table.

What are the possible options.

Thank You
Binu Varghese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1288042643642.html and the examples at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1288042645377.html

The idea is that you set temp options for file name, directory etc, then run a query and the result set is sent to a file. Then you must write a load command in order to load this file. It seems a bit confusing at first but it is very fast